# How to control clang-format indentation of chained method calls?

Tags: c++, indentation, clang-format

I want the results to look like this:

```
auto foo = FooBuilder()
    .WithSomething()
    .WithSomethingElse()
    .Build();
```

but instead `clang-format` formats it like this:

```
auto foo = FooBuilder()
               .WithSomething()
               .WithSomethingElse()
               .Build();
```

I want the chained calls to be indented relative to the beginning of the preceding line, not relative to the `FooBuilder()` call. I don't see anything in the `clang-format` options that control this. Setting `ContinuationIndentWidth` does not help. Any ideas?

Comment: I wonder if this feature is simply missing in clang-format - I've looked and experimented with all the options I knew, and still nothing affects this behavior. For our company, since we use tabs (to my chagrin), we can't avoid mixing spaces and tabs for leading whitespace in this case. Highly annoying - a solution would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Found a hack using clang-format option `PenaltyIndentedWhitespace`.
Increasing this penalty will reformat your core like this:

```cpp
auto foo = 
    FooBuilder()
        .WithSomething()
        .WithSomethingElse()
        .Build();
```

It's not what you wanted initially, however the indent does not depend on `auto foo =`  line length.

For me setting `PenaltyIndentedWhitespace: 1` is working.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this appears to be **not possible.** The only option I have found that affects this at all is `ContinuationIndentWidth`, which, as you said, doesn't do what you want.

What I personally would do is use the following regex to find chained method calls that have been broken up:

`\)\s+\.`

It will match a closing parenthesis, 1 or more whitespace characters (but not 0), and a period. You probably don't have too many instances of this, so you could just fix them manually, and then disable clang-format for those lines so it leaves it alone in the future:

```
// clang-format off

auto friggin_cool_object = SuperCoolBuilder().do_what_i_want()
    .figure()
    .out()
    .the()
    .params()
    .too();

// clang-format on
```