# clang-format controlling indent with multi-line member field/function access

Tags: c++, clang-format

Consider following piece of code (that uses builder-like pattern to construct an object):

```
auto const ci = ::vk::InstanceCreateInfo{}.setPApplicationInfo(&ai).setEnabledExtensionCount(count).setPpEnabledExtensionNames(extensionsArray).setEnabledLayerCount(requiredLayers.size()).setPpEnabledLayerNames(requiredLayers.data());
```

I wish it could be formatted as:

```
auto const ci = ::vk::InstanceCreateInfo{}
    .setPApplicationInfo(&ai)
    .setEnabledExtensionCount(count)
    .setPpEnabledExtensionNames(extensionsArray)
    .setEnabledLayerCount(requiredLayers.size())
    .setPpEnabledLayerNames(requiredLayers.data());
```

But clang insists on:

```
auto const ci = ::vk::InstanceCreateInfo{}
                  .setPApplicationInfo(&ai)
                  .setEnabledExtensionCount(count)
                  .setPpEnabledExtensionNames(extensionsArray)
                  .setEnabledLayerCount(requiredLayers.size())
                  .setPpEnabledLayerNames(requiredLayers.data());
```

How can I control it? There seems to be no option for it (like `AlignMemberAccess`).

Comment: Seems similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39779985/how-to-control-clang-format-indentation-of-chained-method-calls. No answer there either.